# Is DateFormatter broken in Swift 5.1 / Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

**Edit**: I've tried this in an Xcode 11 playground and it functions correctly. What could be causing this?

I was having an issue after updating to XCode 11 where some unit tests that rely on `DateFormatter` were failing. When checking the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) I found the following.

**Apple Example**

```
    let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

    /* 39 minutes and 57 seconds after the 16th hour of December 19th, 1996 with an offset of -08:00 from UTC (Pacific Standard Time) */
    let string = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
    let date = RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

I ran the example code in the swift command line and am getting a nil value returned when trying to parse a date string. Additionally I tried using the current date to output a date string. I believe this shows that the date format string is valid and that there is a bug in `DateFormatter`.

**Apple Example Output**:

```
    Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7).
      1> import Foundation
      2> let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      3> RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
      4> RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
      5> RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
      6> let string = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
      7> let date = RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: string)

    date: Date? = nil

      8> let date = Date()
      9> let dateString = RFC3339DateFormatter.string(from: date)

    dateString: String = "2019-09-27T01:41:09Z"
```

Comment: That code works just fine for me in an Xcode 11 playground.

Comment: @rmaddy This also works fine for me in an Xcode 11 playground. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Same problem with Xcode 12.0.1, and playground still works... @a2hill did you find a solution?